# Responsive WhiteSpace Issue in Next.js Projects

Tags: responsive-design, whitespace

My website large screen is ok but when i try to create responsive my website with inspecting. i faced the problem that is half screen showing and half is whiteSpace. [where is screen issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YUfp.jpg)

I  know that in css if include some width & hight measurement it should fix. but How can i fix this issue to my nextjs project.

In chrome browser i faced this issue. and i am using mac (i think it is not any browser or mac conflict issue).